# Rotate vector by matrix?

Tags: xna, graphics, mathematics, vector, windows-phone-7

If I have a Vector, say (1,1), how can I rotate it around the origin (0,0)?

I'm working in XNA if that helps.

Comment: Is this a question about the mathematics or the implementation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just multiply the vector by a rotation matrix:

```
| fx |     | cos a    -sin a | | sx |
| fy |  =  | sin a     cos a | | sy |
```

where `fx` and `fy` are final coordinates of the object after the rotation and `sx`, `sy` are starting one. Obviously `a` is the angle involved.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are using XNA, there is an easy way to do the above, which can be found in this following [thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/12188/64415.aspx). In shows how to perform the transformation in 3D or 2D. For 2D, it is as simple as:

```
point = Vector2.Transform(point, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(AngleToRotate);
point += originPoint;
```

Note that AngleToRotate is in radians. If you want to use Degrees you can can take advantage of

```
MathHelper.ToRadians(float degree)
```

which is a static method.